# Simulink display local error

Tags: debugging, simulink

Is it possible to display the local error of a integrator step of a variable time step solver in simulink. I would like to find out why simulink is taking small integrator steps. Since the stepsize is depending on the local error of a integration it would be helpful to record the local error. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible from the debugger (as Phil Goddard hinted). Start model in with debugger (from matlab console):

```
>> sldebug mdl
```

Enable "Solver trace level 1"

```
>> strace 1
```

Enable "Break on failed integration step"

```
>> xbreak
```

Start simulation:

```
>> continue
```

The simulation will then break when the local error is too large. For example:

```
[TM = 0.035250948751817182   ] Start of Major Time Step
[Tm = 0.035250948751817182   ] [Hm = 0.0009443691112440444  ] Start of Solver Phase
[Tm = 0.03525094875181718    ] [Hm = 0.0009443691112440444  ] Begin Integration Step
[Tn = 0.03525094875181718    ] [Hn = 0.0009443691112440444  ] Begin Newton Iteration
[Tf = 0.03619531786306122    ] [Hf = 0.0009443691112440444  ] Fail [Er = 6.8210e+00 ] [Ix = 1]
Detected integation step failure. Interrupting model execution
```

The *Er* value is the local error, *Ix* is the state index. To find the corresponding block type:

```
>> states
```

With output

```
Continuous States:
Idx  Value                    (system:block:element  Name   'BlockName')
0  -7.96155746500428e-06    (0:0:0  CSTATE  'mdl/x')
1  1.630758262432841e-12    (0:1:0  CSTATE  'mdl/y')
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the [Simulink Debugger](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/debugging.html)?  If you set breakpoint on the input and output of the block of interest, and run the simulation up to a time when the steps start to become small, then you may be able to determine what's happening.

You might also play around with zero crossing detection.  A pretty good discussion of its basics can be found [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/seth/2013/04/26/zero-crossing-detection-what-are-your-options/).